# Is difference structure PE(32 bit) and PE+ (64 bit )?

Tags: debugging, reverse, portable-executable, hexdump

I know the PE 32 bit structure and i want to know does any difference between PE 32 bit & PE 64 bit (define 64 bit PE Structure)?

Comment: look in `ntimage.h` - all pe structures is defined here.

Answer (score 6):

You should look this link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx
I think you should found your happiness

**EDIT:**

- You have some difference in the import table when you look for name or ordinal in import functions bit is masked as 0x80000000 for PE32, 0x8000000000000000 for PE32+
- The magic number for the image pe format is 0x10b for PE32 and 0x20b for PE32+
- The field BaseOfData in optional header is on PE32 but not in PE32+
- When you relocate you should look if the flag HIGHT_LOW is active for PE32 and DIR64 for PE32+